# Is it possible to edit facebook's built-in forms for my needs?

Tags: facebook, forms

Hi guys I want to prompt a facebook form like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/new-requests.jpg))</sub>

I want just the form itself(the selection of friends) and use it for my needs.
Is it possible to do?  I tried to look for it in the documentation but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a javascript & css library that allows you to show dialogs with a similar look and feet to facebook's. Here is an [example](http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/06/facebook-alertpopup-box-with-jquery-css.html)

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if there were a Facebook Social Plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) to do this. Unfortunately there isn't.

However, as Dimitris says, you can do this yourself easily enough. Just use the Graph API to request a users friends, and generate the table of checkboxes yourself.